# App loads default screen, then either goes black or crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

My app loads the Default.png file and then either crashes or goes black depending on which version I use. It ran fine in SDK3. I went to my console in xcode and found this...

Pending breakpoint 2 - ""OneAppDelegate.m":33" resolved

Pending breakpoint 3 - ""OneAppDelegate.m":82" resolved

Pending breakpoint 4 - ""OneViewController.m":57" resolved

Pending breakpoint 5 - ""OneViewController.m":97" resolved

Program received signal:  “SIGTERM”.

kill

quit

Comment: For the most part when people say their apps ran fine on SDK 3.X and now crash on 4.X it is because they had a bug in their code that for what ever reason isn't being executed or the failure route doesn't cause a crash in 3.X. Its most likely not a change in 4.X but just a old flaw finally showing its head. Have you run static analysis?

Comment: You should show your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method and see this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216336/blank-black-screen-when-running-my-ipad-app/3216476#3216476

Answer (score -1):

what code should I load? The appDelegate h and m files? Or include the view controllers as well?

as for the static analysis, it returns with no errors or warnings

Comment: nick, since stackoverflow isn't like other forums, only post an answer if it's an actual answer to your problem.  otherwise please use the "Edit" link under your original post to update your post or leave a comment like the others have done (otherwise people downvote your response like someone already did)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words of wisdom IWasRobbed! How do I correspond then to someone like yourself who is asking me a question? I'm new here and just trying to find answers.