# applicationDidFinishLaunching not getting called on iPod touch device

Tags: iphone, xcode4, device, ipod-touch

I am working on making what was formerly an iPhone app into a universal app.  And now I am not getting any applicationDidFinishLaunching on an iPod touch device.

The call does come on my iPad.  It also does come on the iPhone simulator.  And on the iPad simulator.  I don't have an iPhone device, so I can't test it there.

Has anyone ever run into anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that in my info.plist, I had the following:

```
Main nib base file name (iPad)       MainWindow_iPad  
Main nib base file name (iPhone)     MainWindow_iPhone
```

That all looks fine and dandy . . . except that before iOS 3.2, the only such key recognized was "Main nib base file name", which was not in my list.  So when I added that, ending up with:

```
Main nib base file name (iPad)       MainWindow_iPad  
Main nib base file name (iPhone)     MainWindow_iPhone  
Main nib base file name              MainWindow_iPhone
```

everything worked great.

I found the clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216336/blank-black-screen-when-running-my-ipad-app).